# JavaFX MySQL Query only showing first result for customerId, but count shows both customers

Tags: mysql

Creating an application in which this specific function is supposed to search the MySQL database for customers with customerId's that have appointments during each specific month, and show customerId on the left column of a TableView and show number of appointments that customer has for a specific month in the right column (Count).

Focusing on December results, the code seems to only be grabbing the first result for customerId, but counts the two appointments in December for Count.  Example, for December, it should show 3 & 4 for customerId on separate rows, with each having 1 for Count in December. Instead the result is 3 for customerId, and Count is 2. Below is the DAO code written, JavaFX is linked to MySQL.

I'm sure it's an issue with the SQL code section as I'm new to coding, but MySQL skills are even lesser. Thank you for any help you may have!

```
public static ObservableList<Report> getDecemberCustomers() {
        ObservableList<Report> monthCustomers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = DBConnection.conn.prepareStatement( 
            "SELECT MONTHNAME(`start`) AS \"month\", customerId AS \"customerId\", COUNT(*) as \"count\" "
            + "FROM appointment "
            + "WHERE MONTH(start) = 12"
        );
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Report monthCustomer = new Report();
                monthCustomer.setMonth(rs.getString("month"));
                monthCustomer.setCustomerId(rs.getInt("customerId"));
                monthCustomer.setCount(rs.getInt("count"));
                monthCustomers.add(monthCustomer);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQL error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    return monthCustomers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query  is missing a `GROUP BY` clause, so it is counting all appointments for all customers into one row, with an indeterminate `customerId` value. You need to `GROUP BY customerId` to get the appointments per customer:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = DBConnection.conn.prepareStatement( 
        "SELECT MONTHNAME(`start`) AS \"month\", customerId AS \"customerId\", COUNT(*) as \"count\" "
        + "FROM appointment "
        + "WHERE MONTH(start) = 12 "
        + "GROUP BY customerId"
    );
```

Dependent on your MySQL version, you may also need to add `month` to the `GROUP BY` i.e. `GROUP BY customerId, month`.